# Why is there so much speed difference between these two variants?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

Version 1:

```
import string, pandas as pd
def correct_contraction1(x, dic):
    for word in dic.keys():
        if word in x:
            x = x.replace(word, " " + dic[word]+ " ")
    return x
```

Version 2:

```
import string, pandas as pd
def correct_contraction2(x, dic):
    for word in dic.keys():
        if " " + word + " " in x:
            x = x.replace(" " + word + " ", " " + dic[word]+ " ")
    return x
```

How I am using them:

```
train['comment_text'] = train['comment_text'].apply(correct_contraction1,args=(contraction_mapping,))
#3 mins 40 sec without that space thing (version1)

train['comment_text'] = train['comment_text'].apply(correct_contraction2,args=(contraction_mapping,))
#5 mins 56 sec with that space thing (version2)
```

Why is there so much speed difference which shouldn't likely be the case and secondly any better/hidden pandas trick to optimize this further? (The code has been tested multiple times on Kaggle Kernels)

- `train` is a data-frame with 2 million rows in both cases, exactly identical as well
- `contraction_mapping` is a dictionary mapping... (same as well in both cases)
- Latest pandas hopefully.

### Edit

- Data comes from the [Kaggle Comp](https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-unintended-bias-in-toxicity-classification/data), Version 1 is way faster!

Comment: Is possible create some data sample for test it?

Comment: Sure, the data used comes from the kaggle comp here https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-unintended-bias-in-toxicity-classification/data

Comment: In version 1 you creates and adds string for each "for" but in version 2 you does it "only if" ?

Comment: I take it version one is the faster of the two?

Comment: (1) Your code is unnecessarily recomputing `" " + word + " "` over and over. You might as well put the spaces in the dictionary keys. (2)  The test `if word in x:` is redundant. The call to `replace()` has to do the presence check anyway.

Comment: Why are you importing re in the second version?

Comment: the code was pasted from my draft, re is used at a later stage(is not needed for testing)(removed)(thanks for the comment)

Comment: @BoarGules If i remove that if check, the time increases to 7.11 mins for me;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry to not answer the difference, but the current approach can be easily improved on in any case. It is going slow for you because you'll have to scan all sentences multiple times (for each word). You're even checking each word twice, first if it is there, and then to replace it - you could just replace only.

This is the crucial lesson when doing text replacement, whether using regex, simple string replacement or even when you develop your own algorithm: try to go over the text only once. Regardless of how many words you want to replace. A regex goes a long way, but depending on the implementation needs to go back a few characters when it does not find a hit. For the interested: look for the trie data structure.

Try for example an implementation of a fast text search (aho-corasick). I'm developing a library for this, but until then, you can use `flashtext` (which does things a little differently):

```
import flashtext
# already considers word boundaries, so no need for " " + word " "
fl = flashtext.KeywordProcessor()
fl.add_keywords_from_dict(dic)

train['comment_text'] = train['comment_text'].apply(fl.replace_keywords)
```

If you have a lot of words to replace, this will be orders of magnitude faster.

For a comparison on the first data I could find:

```
Words to replace: 8520
Sentences to replace in: 11230
Replacements made using flashtext: 1706
Replacements made using correct_contraction1: 25 

flashtext: (considers word boundaries and ignores case)
39 ms ± 355 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

correct_contraction1: (does not consider case nor words at end of line)
11.9 s ± 194 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

<unannounced>
30 ms ± 366 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So we are talking a 300x speedup. That doesn't happen every day ;-)

For reference, added the regex way by Jon Clements:

```
pandas.str.replace + regex (1733 replacements)
3.02 s ± 82.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

My new lib will shave off another 30% as I tested it. I've seen 2-3x improvement over flashtext too, but more importantly, give you, as user, more control. It's fully functional, just need to clean it up and add more documentation.

I'll update the answer when it arrives!

Comment: Not sure why but this throws an error later "IndexError: string index out of range"; will try ti find the cause; thanks for the lib\

Comment: Both versions do the scan twice, so this doesn't explain the speed difference between them.

Comment: @Aditya Make sure you do not try to add an empty string I guess?

Comment: Here's the collection in case it helps people visiting this query in future https://gist.github.com/AdityaSoni19031997/d16d2796c26ce80b27b0e0da80a9f10f

Comment: What is really funny is that I've created https://github.com/kootenpv/contractions that could help you a little haha. Though once my new lib comes out I will take the logic of contractions and implement it in a way faster way. I was also making the mistake of scanning the text multiple times there! Stay tuned.

Comment: @PascalVKooten  The error arises because of the fa t that sometimes lowering few characters can make their length increase, nothing wrong with the mapping :)

Answer (score 1):

You're better of using Pandas' `Series.str.replace` here and providing it a compiled regular expression based on the contents of a lookup table. This means the string replacement operations can work on the Series quicker than applying a function, it also means you're not scanning the string way, way more times than you need to... Hopefully it'd reduce your time down to seconds instead of minutes.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

corrections = {
    "it's": "it is",
    "can't": "can not",
    "won't": "will not",
    "haven't": "have not"
}

sample = pd.Series([
    "Stays the same",
    "it's horrible!",
    "I hope I haven't got this wrong as that won't do",
    "Cabbage"
])
```

Then build your regex so that it looks for for any possible matches that are keys in your dictionary, case insensitively and honouring word boundaries:

```
rx = re.compile(r'(?i)\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(re.escape(c) for c in corrections)))
```

Then apply to your column (change `sample` to `training['comment_text']` for instance) a `str.replace` passing the regex and a function that takes the match and returns the matching value for the key found:

```
corrected = sample.str.replace(rx, lambda m: corrections.get(m.group().lower()))
```

Then you'll have `corrected` as a Series containing:

```
['Stays the same',
 'it is horrible!',
 'I hope I have not got this wrong as that will not do',
 'Cabbage']
```

Note the casing of `It's`... it's been case insensitively picked up and made into `it is` instead... There's various ways to preserve case but it's probably not massively important and a different question altogether.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the tip as well;(was about to convert them to re.compile and then re.sub)

Comment: Note that `\b`  won't work if keywords can start/end with special regex metacharacters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm `re.escape`'ing all the keywords first though... is there anything else I'm missing there?

Comment: `\b\(` will only match in `a(` and not in `a (`.

Answer (score 1):

The second version has to perform the concatenation `" " + word + " "` every time through the loop, and when it finds a match it does it a second time to perform the replacement. This makes it slower.

You can't avoid the first concatenation (unless you modify `dic` so the keys already have spaces around them). But you can avoid the second concatenation by saving it in a variable the first time. It will still be slower than the first version, but not by as much.

```
def correct_contraction2(x, dic):
    for word in dic.keys():
        spaceword = " " + word + " "
        if spaceword in x:
            x = x.replace(spaceword, " " + dic[word]+ " ")
    return x
```

It also seems like the second version might not work correctly in all cases. If the word is at the beginning or end of a line, it won't be surrounded by spaces. It might be better to use a regular expression with `\b` to match word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the tip as well;